# Why object reference is not changed as well in the collection it's stored?

Tags: java, oop, collections

I'm playing with some piece of code, and I was expecting a different result. For instance, if I have some `Person` objects, and the same are added to a collection (any), later modified it (one or more members), **isn't supposed to that reference should be updated as well in the collection(s) where it's being referenced/added?**

This is the piece of code I was "playing" with:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
  Person robert = new Person("Robert", "Virding", 59);
  Person mike = new Person("Mike", "Williams", 62);
  Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Armstrong", 65);
  List<Person> persons = new LinkedList<>();

  persons.add(robert);
  persons.add(mike);
  persons.add(joe);

  Collection<Person> immutable = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(persons);

  joe = new Person("Joe", "Jonas", 35);
  System.out.printf("[robert] %s%n", robert);
  System.out.printf("[mike] %s%n", mike);
  System.out.printf("[joe] %s%n", joe);
  System.out.printf("[persons] %s%n", persons);
  System.out.printf("[immutable] %s%n", immutable);
}
```

My understanding is that object `joe` should be `Person {givenName=Joe, familyName=Jonas, age=35}` instead of `Person {givenName=Joe, familyName=Armstrong, age=65}`; but that is not happening for the reference(s) inside the collection(s).

Any advice?

For the record, this is the output I'm getting:

```
[robert] Person{givenName=Robert, familyName=Virding, age=59}
[mike] Person{givenName=Mike, familyName=Williams, age=62}
[joe] Person{givenName=Joe, familyName=Jonas, age=35}
[persons] [Person{givenName=Robert, familyName=Virding, age=59}, Person{givenName=Mike, familyName=Williams, age=62}, Person{givenName=Joe, familyName=Armstrong, age=65}]
[immutable] [Person{givenName=Robert, familyName=Virding, age=59}, Person{givenName=Mike, familyName=Williams, age=62}, Person{givenName=Joe, familyName=Armstrong, age=65}]
```

Comment: When you assigned `new Person("Joe", "Jonas", 35)` to the variable `joe`, you disconnected the original reference assigned to the `joe` variable.  In order to put the reference to the new joe object now held in the `joe` variable into `persons`, you have to `add` it to the `persons` collection, or reassign the reference contained in the list.  The unmodifiable collection is, of course, unmodifiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list has a reference to the object ["Joe", "Armstrong", 65] and your variable has a reference to the second one which is ["Joe", "Jonas", 35] and that's because you created a new object and assigned it to `joe`. The List doesn't keep references to variables like "joe", it holds a reference to the object itself.

Comment: That's a better explanation of what's happening.

Answer (score -1):

First, when you create the object `joe`, there is only one reference to one object:

```
Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Armstrong", 65);
```

Then you add it to the list, creating a new reference to the same object:

```
persons.add(joe);
```

Now there are 2 references, one is `joe` and one is maintained inside of the collection `persons`. Now in the final step you change your reference:

```
joe = new Person("Joe", "Jonas", 35);
```

Now you have created a new object, and with it a new reference. There are now 2 references and 2 separate objects: one is `joe` that refers to the second object, and the other is maintained inside of the collection that refers to the original `joe` object.

Comment: I was pretty sure the first answerer wouldn't explain it clearly.  I was right.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Then you should answer the question yourself so I can bow to your wizardry.

Comment: I already left a comment, but to answer the question clearly, you're going to need charts and graphs and an easel.